# If $U,V$ are left $A$-modules, then is $U \otimes V$ a left $A \otimes A$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, algebras

Let $A$ be a unital associative algebra over the field $k$ and $U,V$ left $A$-modules. A book I'm reading claims that $U \otimes V$ is a left $A \otimes A$-module.

First, how is the tensor product taken? Since $k \subseteq A$, we have that $U$ and $V$ are $k$-vector spaces so we can consider $U \otimes_k V$ and I'm guessing this is what $U \otimes V$ denotes. Then, on this we want to put an $A \otimes A$-module structure.

I guess this is given by
$$(a \otimes b). (u \otimes v)= (au) \otimes (bv)$$?

One then must check this is wel-defined and determines a unique action (we only said what it does to basis elements). Is my above interpretation correct?

Comment: According to tensor product, in your example $V$ should be $\text{right}$  $A$-module  and $W$ should be $\text{left}$ $A$-module

Comment: But that is the case here?

Comment: @user745578: $U$ and $V$ are left $A$-modules, and hence also left $k$-modules. But since $k$ is commutative, any left $k$-module is actually a $k$-bimodule. Thus $U\otimes_k V$ is well-defined.

Comment: @user745578 I'll withdraw what I wrote for now since I can't confirm or deny my doubts. Qiaochu Yuan seems to implicitly confirm it [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/107844/19965) , but like the passage you cited did not deign to mention details about it.

Comment: Yeah, the text I'm reading does not really give any details too. It is in the book Quantum Groups by Kassel, p285. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: The comments in your link make me think I'm on the right track, since I have a comultiplication map $\Delta: A \to A \otimes A$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is what you need to prove. I agree that the book probably uses $\otimes$ to denote $\otimes_k$.

To show that the multiplication is well-defined, it is enough to show that $(a,b,u,v)\mapsto (au)\otimes(bv)$ is $k$-linear in each argument (which easily follows from the hypothesis that $U,V$ are $A$-modules). This will give you a $k$-bilinear map $(A\otimes_k A)\times (U\otimes_k V)\to (U\otimes_k V)$.

By bilinearity, to show that this is an action of $A\otimes_k A$, it is enough that you have mixed associativity for simple tensors. But this easily follows from mixed associativity for $U$ and $V$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your interpretation is correct.

You should check conventions on what exactly $\otimes$ means, as it could also potentially mean tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$. (I doubt that is the case, but I suppose it could happen.) But certainly, your interpretation is a reasonable one.